# ng-src: show a throbber before an image is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have implemented an interface where the user can cycle through a set of images by clicking buttons. The image URLs are stored in an array and are replaced by angular.js dynamically:

```
<img ng-src="{currentUrl}">
```

However, the requests for consecutive images tend to lag a bit and the image change isn't apparent since the previous image is displayed until the new one arrives.

I would like to replace the image with a throbber (animated gif). How can I achieve that using Angular.js?

Comment: why not just use <img src="fake_small_image.gif" data-src="real_image.jpg"> ?

Comment: @Andreas You do realise you're over 4 years late, don't you?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can do this with a directive which replaces your image with a spinner whenever the path changes and shows the image when it is loaded.

```
  <img my-src="{{currentUrl}}">

  app.directive("mySrc", function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var img, loadImage;
        img = null;

        loadImage = function() {

          element[0].src = "pathToSpinner";

          img = new Image();
          img.src = attrs.mySrc;

          img.onload = function() {
            element[0].src = attrs.mySrc;
          };
        };

        scope.$watch((function() {
          return attrs.mySrc;
        }), function(newVal, oldVal) {
          if (oldVal !== newVal) {
            loadImage();
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: beaten... and his got $watch there

Comment: Nice one! I tried writing a directive that would "talk to" ngSrc, but failed to achieve what I wanted. Your version leaves ngSrc out of the picture completely and I guess this is the approach I should've taken from the very start. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you must call loadImage() at the end of link function to load initial image

Comment: I've corrected this awesome answer with just slight changes. `<img my-src="{ currentUrl }">` ==>> `<img my-src="{{ currentUrl }}">`

Answer (score 11):

I know its pretty late but i do it like

```
<img src="img/loader.gif" ng-src={{dynamicImageURL}}>
```

by default your loader img will show and later when dynamicImageURL gets resolved, the image will be replaced by angular.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with CSS.  Set the background of the img tag to the animated gif. The background will show until the image is loaded.

```
    img{
      background-image: url('throbber.gif') no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: Like I said, Angular.js shows the previous image until the new one is loaded, so the throbber is actually never displayed save for when the very first image is still loading.

Comment: I think you'll need an extra dom element to show then. Show the element with the throbber when the button is clicked and hide it when the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use a directive, the directive below only works for a single image but you'll want to use `attr.$watch` to detect changes to the imageIndex or src attribute of the element.

```
myModule.directive('imgLoader', function() {
  return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
        // get the parent and chuck bg image in
        var parent = element.parent();
        parent.css('background-image', 'url("path-to-throbber.gif")');
        parent.css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
        // when it loads, hide the bg
        element.load(function() {
           parent.css('background-image','');
           parent.css('background-repeat','');
        });
     }
  }
});
```

You could always not use the `ng-src` attribute, but have another attribute to watch, and then simply set the "src" attribute when the source image changes.

Hope this helps